# appending data from loop php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having an issue appending data from loop. I am trying to append the result that is clicked on, but when theres multiple results every result is appended on click. I am using ajax to retrieve search results. Below is my php section. I think the issue is that every result has the same class so it appends every one, but I can't figure out how to identify only one

```
if(isset($_POST['inviteSearch'])) {

include_once "connect.php";

$con = getConnection();
$search = "%{$_POST['inviteSearch']}%";

$query = "SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM `Profiles` WHERE FirstName LIKE ? OR LastName LIKE ? ";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $search ,$search);

if(!($stmt->execute())) {

    die(mysql_error());    

} else {

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $output = '<ol>';
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            $name = $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];

            $output .= "
            <li id='invitetoken'>

            <p>$name</p>

            </li>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#invitetoken').click(function(){
                    $('.invitedSection').show();
                    $('.invitedList').append('<li><p>$name</p><button>&times;</button></li>');
                });
            });
            </script>

            ";

        }
    } else {
        $output .= "<h3>We could not find $search</h3>";
    }
    $output .= '</ol>';
    echo "$output";

}
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: In MySQL `x OR y = z` is not the same as `x=z OR y=z`. Same goes for `LIKE` instead of `=`.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @tadman i edited..do you have any thoughts on my appending problem though?

Comment: Why go through all the trouble of appending when you can just `echo` straight up? You can even close your PHP tag and have it echo out for you by default, that can keep your code more orderly.

Comment: @tadman i should have added this in the question but I am echoing the results and when they click on a certain result they are appending that to another list..the second list I will then be inserting into a table (the other list is on the ajax page that isnt posted but the class im appending too is visible here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with the obvious, please use parameterized queries you are currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

You are appending the same js repeatedly in your while loop, that is generally bad practice. I'm going to break this up a bit, since you have both php and JS issues

## PHP

Here just generally cleaning up and using parameterized queries and class based mysqli (in line with the above suggestion comments). I also moved the javascript out of the loop as repeating it over and over doesn't achieve anything. Obviously haven't tested my changes but they are fairly boilerplate (see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php))

```
if (!isset($_POST[''inviteSearch']) {
  return;
}

$connection = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'schema');
$param = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'inviteSearch', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

// setup query
$query = "SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS name
  FROM Profiles
  WHERE (FirstName LIKE ? OR LastName LIKE ?)";

// prepare statement
$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
// need variable bind for each tokenized parameter
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $param, $param); 
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->get_result();

$output = makeOutput($results);

// Siloing your presentational elements for clarity.
function makeOutput($results) {
  if ($results->num_rows === 0) {
    return "<h3>We could not find $search</h3>";
  }

  $output = '<ol>';
  while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output .= "<li class='invitetoken'><p>{$row['name']}</p></li>";
  }
  $output .= '</ol>';

  return $output;
}
```

## JavaScript

A few things here, enclosed the function into an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to keep it namespace contained, generally a good practice. The changes to the click handler let the callback handle the update dynamically for any matching class that is clicked. I reference `this` (in this case it is helpful to think of `this` as `event.target`) and use it to find the name to be appended. from there it is pretty similar to what you already had.  Of note, I'm using `let` for variable definitions and template literal syntax for the string data, but you should look up their availability and decide whether you need to worry about old browser support :).

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.invitetoken').on('click', function() {
      let name = $(this).children('p').text()
      ,   string = `<li><p>${name}</p><button>&times;</button></li>`;

      $('.invitedSection').show();
      $('.invitedList').append(string);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: First of all thank you for taking the time to answer my question..secondly, the only issue that I am having is that when it appends the 'p' is not showing up. the error is undefined variable: name.. i played around with the script a little bit and got the error to go away but the p would still not append..the li and button is appending but the p is absent..any ideas?

Comment: hmm, I would say that `$(this).children('p').text()` might not be finding anything. You might need to do some console debugging to get this exactly correct.  see what `$(this)` or `$(this).children()` give you. That will probably help find where that selector is going wrong.

Comment: Got it!                                                                                                           
var name = $(this).text();
var str1 = '<li><p>';
var str2 = name;
var str3 = '</p><button>&times;</button></li>';
string = str1.concat(str2, str3);